Install debian on an old android tablet to replace android
For several months now, I want to install Debian on my old android tablet but I'm unable to find any resources on how to do it.
Here is the model of the table:
Superpad 7 (crane bc1003 according to adb) made in 2013
with:
Allwinner sun4i (aka Allwinner A10, cortex A8 running ARMv7)
1GB RAM
16GB Storage
RJ45 Port
3G/GSM + WiFi
2 USB-A ports
1 HDMI
1 Audio combo jack
1 TF card slot.

According to ADB, i have an unknown bootloader (wait, what?) and i can't reboot inside it (adb reboot fastboot / adb reboot recovery not working)
I actually managed to install clockworkmod on this and i managed to dump everything including boot.img using their backup tool. You can download everything from there:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cPvPbzvZzE_za3l3pKjKPt5tRu6z2iCv/view?usp=sharing (200MB)
It is currently running the Linux 3.0.8+ Kernel from jackie@ubuntu and it is running Android 4.0.4.
Do someone know how to flash debian from CWM recovery ?
PS: I don't have any personnal data contained in the back, so go ahead !
